# Matching a pattern and joining two lines below to one line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have an irregular file which I want to join the 3 lines when **net** is seen then join the next two lines

```
abscc.tech.com
________
________
eaaa.bang.com
________
________
pop.wow.com
________
net self 10.47.250.189 
    address 10.47.250.189/29
    vlan trust_f5_1293
net self 10.47.96.12 
    address 10.47.96.12/24
    vlan vips_inline_1096
________
yuum.bean.com
________
```

The Result should be

```
abscc.tech.com
________
________
eaaa.bang.com
________
________
pop.wow.com
________
net self 10.47.250.189 address 10.47.250.189/29 vlan trust_f5_1293
net self 10.47.96.12 address 10.47.96.12/24 vlan vips_inline_1096
________
yuum.bean.com
________
```

I tried

```
awk '/net/{if (NR!=1)print "";next}{printf $0}END{print "";}' file.txt
```

but it just begins from the first 'net' and becomes garbles after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^net/{c=3} c&&c--{sub(/^ +/," "); rec=rec sep $0; if (c>0) next; $0=rec; rec=""} 1' file
abscc.tech.com
________
________
eaaa.bang.com
________
________
pop.wow.com
________
net self 10.47.250.189 address 10.47.250.189/29 vlan trust_f5_1293
net self 10.47.96.12 address 10.47.96.12/24 vlan vips_inline_1096
________
yuum.bean.com
________
```

If you need to join 50 lines instead of 3 just replace `3` with `50`. Consider how to do that with the other answers. It'd also be trivial to do further manipulation on the target block of text, introduce error checking, redirect that block to a different file or do anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `awk` for this to match the line starting with `net`, get the next two lines with `getline()` and print them *while* printing the other two lines by default.

```
awk '/^net/ { getline first; getline second; 
              sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",first); 
              sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",second); 
              printf "%s %s %s\n",$0, first, second; next }{ print }' file
```

Comment: Similar, but terser: `awk '$1 == "net" {printf "%s",$0; getline; printf "%s",$0; getline}1'`

Comment: That will quietly produce corrupted output given various getline failures. For example if there's only 1 lines after a specific `net` then the above will duplicate that line. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline. There's no reason to use getline for a task like this.

Comment: @EdMorton: Perfectly agree with that Ed. Used it _only_ because OP had mentioned 2 lines following `net`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with `sed`:

`sed -e '/^net/{N;s/\n//;N;s/\n//;}'` file

It searches for the pattern, line starting with a 'net', `^net`

brings in the next line, `N`

deletes the embedded newline, `s/\n//`

it does the same twice in order to remove two new lines.